# Losing sort order when creating a tree from array

Tags: php, laravel-5

Based on a previous question on how to create a tree from a nested array with parent ID's, I now have an almost completed script. The only thing is that in the output json the ordering is messed up. This is due that the array is now build on parent_id instead of the ordering by database field 'sorting.'

Can any one help me figure out where and how to make a change for it to work, that in the json the item with the lowest number in 'sorting' is listed first?

```
public function sorting() {
    $pages = Page::orderBy('sorting')->get()->toArray();
    $new = array();
    foreach ($pages as $page){
        $new[$page['parent_id']][] = $page;
    }
    $tree = $this->createTree($new, $new[0]);
    return view('base\backend\pages\sorting', [
        'pages' => json_encode($tree)
    ]);
}

private function createTree(&$list, $parent){
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($parent as $key=>$item){
        if(isset($list[$item['id']])){
            $item['children'] = $this->createTree($list, $list[$item['id']]);
        }
        $tree[] = $item;
    }
    return $tree;
}
```

Found/created the solution: This is working very well. My mistake was that the parent id's were never reset to zero, thus messing up the sort order.

Comment: can't, really, not without changing the tree completely. you've build a tree with a different keying system, and it's going to be output based on that key system. if you don't want it output that way, then don't use that keying system.

Comment: Marc, what do you suggest? As I do want this kind of tree view

Comment: maybe a composite key? `"$sort-$id"`?

Comment: You now need to supply some real data and exactly how you want it look. Not the easy stuff but the hard stuff that you cannot make sense of. I suspect as you try and describe it to us - you will learn about it? We need to see what data you have and exactly how you want it to look. Also, Provide some clues as to how you tried to make it look right and came second. my fear is that, you may be asking the impossible, but not realizing it.

Comment: Thanx Ryan... I got it working. I will update my question with how I did it

Comment: Ryan, I know, but the problem was in a way other function that actually was not of any concern to this tree generation functionality